# why setting IFS to newline character '\n' also take pure alphabet n as part of IFS?

Tags: linux, bash

This is my basic shell file to know about IFS

```
PROGRAMMING="
java programming 
python programming 
c programming 
"

echo "--------------------"
for p in $PROGRAMMING; do
        echo $p
done

echo "--------------------"
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=\n
for p in $PROGRAMMING;do
        echo $p
done

IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

following result is listed below

```
--------------------
java
programming
pytho
programming
c
programming
--------------------

java programmi
g 
pytho programmi
g 
c programmi
g
```

how come newly set IFS also count pure alphabet 'n' as part of IFS?

Comment: Try `IFS=$'\n'`.

Comment: Or at least `IFS="\n"`

Answer (score 0):

> why setting IFS to newline character '\n' also take pure alphabet n as part of IFS?

Because `\n` is just the same as `n`. `\n` has no special meaning *in this context*, `\n` means just `n`.

```
$ echo \n
n
$ var=\n
$ echo "$var"
n
```

> how come newly set IFS also count pure alphabet 'n' as part of IFS?

You set `IFS=n`, so `IFS` is splitting on character `n`.

If you want a newline, you can use ANSI-C quoting style `IFS=$'\n'` or write the newline literally between quotes.